# Docker "unknown flag: --from"

Tags: docker, fedora

I am trying to build an image using simple Dockerfile. However I am unable to get passed the above issue. I came across a kb article saying that I have to enable the "edge" repo. I have since done that, however it has made no difference.

I am using the following version :

Client: 
 Version:         1.13.1 
 API version:     1.26 
 Package version: docker-1.13.1-56.git6c336e4.fc28.x86_64 
 Go version:      go1.10.2 
 Git commit:      1ab62f1-unsupported 
 Built:           Thu May 24 20:48:50 2018 
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64

Server: 
 Version:         1.13.1 
 API version:     1.26 (minimum version 1.12) 
 Package version: docker-1.13.1-56.git6c336e4.fc28.x86_64 
 Go version:      go1.10.2 
 Git commit:      1ab62f1-unsupported 
 Built:           Thu May 24 20:48:50 2018 
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64 
 Experimental:    false

If someone can tell me what I should try to get this feature working, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your installation is over a year out of date and no longer supported. It looks like you need to redirect your install to the new package repositories that started with the ce/ee rebranding. Follow the directions for your Linux distribution to upgrade to at least 18.03.1-ce.

https://docs.docker.com/install/

Seeing the tag on your question, the fedora specific steps are here: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/fedora/

Comment: Thanks for that. I wasn't sure if it was the current version or not, as I had recently upgraded from Fedora 27 to 28. The Docker version in the "Update" repo obviously wasn't the current version. I had to uninstall the old version of Docker before I could install the current version from the docker-edge repo.